# Game Maker WASD and arrow keys smooth rotation?

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

How can I make smooth rotation using WASD or arrow keys? I saw some exaples, but they all use mouse. I surely want to use WASD or arrow keys. I really hope someone can help me with this.

This is my code so far.

```
// You can write your code in this editor
if(keyboard_check_pressed(ord("W"))) or (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_up)){
    speed = sailSpeed;
    image_speed = 1;
}
if(keyboard_check_released(ord("W"))) or (keyboard_check_released(vk_up)){
    speed = 0;
    image_speed = 0;
    image_index = 0;
}
if(keyboard_check_pressed(ord("D"))) or keyboard_check_pressed(vk_right){
    direction -= 45;
}
if(keyboard_check_pressed(ord("A"))) or keyboard_check_pressed(vk_left){
    direction += 45;
}

if(direction == 0) or (direction == 360) or (direction == -360){
    sprite_index = sprPlayerShipRight;
}
if(direction == 45) or (direction == -315){
    sprite_index = sprPlayerShipUpRight;
}
if(direction == 90) or (direction == -270){
    sprite_index = sprPlayerShipUp;
}
if(direction == 135) or (direction == -225){
    sprite_index = sprPlayerShipUpLeft;
}
if(direction == 180) or (direction == -180){
    sprite_index = sprPlayerShipLeft;
}
if(direction == 225) or (direction == -135){
    sprite_index = sprPlayerShipDownLeft;
}
if(direction == 270) or (direction == -90){
    sprite_index = sprPlayerShipDown;
}
if(direction == 315) or (direction == -45){
    sprite_index = sprPlayerShipDownRight;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn by 45 degrees your sprite in a "smoothly" way, the only thing that you can do is to draw, let's say, another 3 mid-frames to the turning. Anyway, the more sprites the more smooth the animation will be. You can't make a smooth turning with just two sprites.

Don't rely on the turning function of GM, better to draw the frames by yourself, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you're after?

```
directionHorizontal = (keyboard_check(ord("D")) - keyboard_check(ord("A"));
directionVertical = (keyboard_check(ord("S")) - keyboard_check(ord("W"));
directionMoving = point_direction(0, 0, directionHorizontal, directionMoving);
var directionDifference = angle_difference(direction , directionMoving );
direction -= min(abs(directionDifference ), 10) * sign(directionDifference);
```

Edit: Sorry, I misread. It sounds like you're after acceleration and deceleration of the turning speed. What I would do is this:

Add approach() to your project:
https://pastebin.com/7gzJTLKj

Initialize these variables in the create event:

```
turningSpeed = 0;
turningSpeedMax = 15;
turningSpeedIncrement = 1;
```

And in the step event, you can have this:

```
turningDirection = (keyboard_check(ord("D")) - keyboard_check(ord("A")));
turningSpeed = approach(turningSpeed, turningSpeedMax * turningDirection, turningSpeedIncrement);
direction += turningSpeedIncrement;
```

Comment: I want that W accelerates and A and D are for turning.

Comment: But when I'm near my PC again I'll try that. Sounds something to try.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post -- I changed my response to a different solution

Comment: I will surely try this once I'm near my PC again. But thanks for answering. I appreciate it! :)

Comment: It kind of worked, but I want my player sprite to turn smoothly 45 degrees with one key press. Is this possible? And how I can turn the sprite too?